# Unknown CMake command "add_clang_executable"

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, clion

I am trying to build a clang tool, and I am trying to debug it using CLion. However, I can't get it to compile as a standalone binary. Currently I have this in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_clang_executable(clang_my_tool my_tool_util.h my_tool_util.cpp ClangMyTool.cpp)

target_link_libraries(clang_my_tool PRIVATE clangTooling)
```

However, it's giving me the error message:

```sh
Unknown CMake command "add_clang_executable".
```

I know I need to add an directory, but I don't know *which* one to add.

My `llvm` directory looks something like this:

```
llvm
|-build
  |- ...
|
|-clang
  |-tools
    |-clang_my_tool
      |-ClangMyTool.cpp
      |-my_tool_util.h
      |-my_tool_util.c
      |-CMakeLists.txt
|- ... other directories...
```

**What do I add to my CMakeLists.txt?**

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/LibTooling-CMake-Error-td4027570.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, this is what I want, basically. However, the [link provided in the thread](https://github.com/philipc/clang-ast/blob/master/CMakeLists.standalone) unfortunately links to a 5-year old repostiory, and doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the LLVM CMakeLists.txt file which defines `add_clang_executable()`.  Currently that file is here (and may well already be installed on your system): https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/cmake/modules/AddClang.cmake

If you figure out the path to that file on your system, add this to your own `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include("/path/to/AddClang.cmake")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since paths in clang are relative, even if I add this, CMake will fail:
```
fatal error: clang/AST/Attr.h: No such file or directory
 #include "clang/AST/Attr.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```
Due to how the include statements are in the [clang source code itself](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Attr_8h_source.html) -- it's all relative from the top directory

Comment: @gust: I think you can solve that by adding some `-I` rules to your compiler command, so it finds the headers relative to whatever directory you specify.

Comment: `-I` rules to compilers?